eval for pathnames from mkdir -p
I am writing a script to move around a bit of data, which I want to be able to create the parent directory to where I am sending my data, in order to do some renaming/cleaning of filenames I need to keep track of the newly created directories so I can change the permissions to the set input argument.
Seeing as mkdir -vp can output the created directories it felt perfect, however, I am unable to dereference the quotes to be able to use the output, and eval seems the only option. I am aware that I could probably just loop and check if each directory exist, but it seems wasteful when mkdir outputs it already.
This is my code as of now:
readarray -t ndir < <(ssh myhost mkdir -vp foo/ | grep -oP "^mkdir: created directory\s+\K['\"].+['\"](?=$)" | sort -r)
eval ndir=("${ndir[@]}")
ssh myhost chmod 555 "${ndir[@]}"

EDIT: If foo was a path with newlines, or other special character they will be quoted in $'..' format, which is why I started using eval.
It is my understanding that eval is as close to evil as you can come, but I don't see any viable and as convenient solution other than manually looping over and checking which parts of the path exist. Is there a safer, and alternative way?

There are many ways to remove the unwanted quotes. First of all, you can just stop generating them (by using regex "^mkdir: created directory\s+['\"]\K.+(?=['\"]$)" instead, for example). You can also pipe the whole thing to xargs - that will work if your input is "good" and doesn't contain unbalanced quotes. You can use bash variable slicing (${var:1:-1}) (since you know the exact format, but that's a modern feature). You can use bash prefix/suffix removal (${var#\'} and ${var%\'} if I remember correctly). Last two would need looping.

and if the name of a directory created has a newline in it, GNU mkdir uses $'..' escapes, e.g. mkdir: created directory 'foo'$'\n''bar', so it looks like it tries to make the output shell-compatible. (Whereas the BSD mkdir on my mac just prints foo and bar on two lines, and doesn't output any quotes anyway.)

but, there's mkdir -m 555 to set the directory mode; is there a reason not to just use that?

FWIW, ssh (well, sshd on the server side) does the equivalent of eval as the arguments you pass to ssh are concatenated with spaces (like eval does) and the result is evaluated as shell code by the login shell of the remote user, so it is as "evil" as eval in this case. Even worse because you don't know what shell it will be (and what syntax to use for quoting) and what locale will be used to decode those arguments as text.

@StéphaneChazelas Ouch, that's unfortunate, is there any good solution to it?

@SUTerliakov The issue is as @ilkkachu pointed out, any newline would create $'..' format, if I leave the quotations, the strings cannot be eval since they in reality contain a horror amount of quotations. But maye the ugly solution is to do what @StéphaneChazelas pointed out, which is to feed it to ssh anyhow, since it evals it.

@ilkkachu unfortunately, yes, these are the parent directories I will be moving all of my files, after the move I want to rename them to clean out special characters and whatnot. I want to avoid renaming on device or on another remote as not to modify the original content. And so the directories need to be writeable until everything is done. In the best of worlds, rsync would have reported any paths created with --mkpath

Related: How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?

There are several questions in there:

how to make a directory with r-xr-xr-x as permissions
how to pass an arbitrary list of file paths to a remote command
how to retrieve the list of directories that have been successfully created by a mkdir command run remotely.

Making a directory with with r-xr-xr-x permissions
mkdir -pm a=rx a/b/c

Or more portably (though both are standard):
mkdir -pm 555 a/b/c

Would create a/b/c with r-xr-xr-x as permissions. If the directory already existed, including if it was a symlink to a directory, then it still succeeds but does not change the permission of the directory.
If the a or a/b did not exist beforehand, they'll be created with rwxrwxrwx as the permissions, possibly modified by the current umask, though the w and x bits for user are forced on so as to be able to create the child path components. So:
umask a=rx # or umask 222
mkdir -p a/b/c

Would make a/b/c with r-xr-xr-x permissions and possibly a and a/b with rwxr-xr-x permissions, and return true if and only if a/b/c can be confirmed to be a file of type directory (or symlink to directory) upon exit. Permissions of already existing directories are not modified.
Without -p, mkdir would only create a/b/c and return failure if it can't including if a/b doesn't exist or a/b/c already exists even as a directory.
install -dm a=rx a/b/c

Is another way to create a directory. There are a few differences compared to mkdir -p:

if a/b/c existed beforehand but did not have the requested permissions, the permissions will be amended, and it will report failure if it can't. If a/b/c is a symlink to a directory, it's the permission of that directory that will be amended.
a, and a/b will be created if missing, but with u=rwx,go=rx as permission, regardless of umask and regardless of the permissions given to -m.
install, contrary to mkdir is more of a development command and is not standard, so may not be found on every system.

Or you could use the make_path function of perl's File::Path Module, which as it happens can be given a mode (but u=wx bits need to be set for it to create multi-level paths) and returns the paths of the directories it has created.
$ perl -MFile::Path=make_path -le 'print qq(I have created "$_") for make_path("a/b", {chmod => 0755, error => \$err})'
I have created "a"
I have created "a/b"

(passing a error parameter prevents it from exiting upon error).
Then you can apply the 0555 chmod in reverse order with something like:
perl -MFile::Path=make_path -le 'chmod 0555, reverse make_path("a/b/c", {error => \$err})'

how to pass an arbitrary list of file paths to a remote command
That is covered at length at How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?.
Specifically here, if the remote system has a xargs that is POSIX2024 compliant (supports -r and -0 à la GNU):
print0() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"; }
print0 "${dirs[@]}" | ssh user@host 'umask a=rx && xargs -r0 mkdir -p --'

(with zsh, print0 can also be written: print -rNC1 --)
How to retrieve the list of directories that have been successfully created by a mkdir command ran remotely.
Using mkdir -v for that would be quite brittle. First, it's not a standard option, the output format is not specified by any standard. The few mkdir implementations that support it don't document the output format, it's primarily intended for human consumption. The GNU implementation of mkdir seems to do some shell-like form of quoting, but it doesn't say it does, let alone the syntax of which shell and version thereof that would be. In any case, unless you use only single quotes for quoting, quote parsing is usually locale-dependant, so you'd need to make sure the same locale is used on the remote machine where the output is produced and on the local machine where it's interpreted.
mkdir: created directory may be what current versions of GNU mkdir output in US-English locales, but there's no telling what it will be in the next version or in other locales.
The busybox implementation of mkdir just wraps the paths in '...', whether they contain ' or newlines or not and output created directory rather than mkdir: created directory.
If you fix the locale to C on client and server and you can assume that mkdir on the remote host is the GNU implementation, of the versions that quote paths using Korn shell style of quoting where newline is always quoted as \n within the $'...' form of quoting and which in the C locale outputs mkdir: created directory <quoted-text>.
Then you could decode those paths by switching to zsh instead of bash and use its Q unquote parameter expansion flag which happens to understand all the quoting forms used in the verbose output of current versions of the GNU implementation of mkdir:
export LC_ALL=C
created_dirs=( ${(Qf)"$(
  set -o pipefail
  print -rNC1 -- $dirs | ssh user@host '
    umask 222 && env LC_ALL=C xargs -r0 mkdir -vp --' |
    sed -n 's/^mkdir: created directory //p')"}
)

(here using umask 222 and env in case the login shell of user on host is (t)csh whose umask doesn't support the symbolic form nor the ENV=value cmd syntax).
With bash locally and perl remotely, you can do the transfer file path safely, make_path, chmod, return the created list safely with:
print0() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"; }
readarray -td '' created_dirs < <(
  print0 "${dirs[@]}" | ssh user@host '
    perl -MFile::Path=make_path -0le '\''
      @created = make_path(<>, {error => \$err});
      chmod 0555, reverse @created;
      print for @created'\'
)

(assuming the shell of the remote user is not (t)csh, with which you'd need to put that shell code on one line).
Or with zsh:
#! /bin/zsh -
dirs=(
  'foo/bar baz'
  '../x/y'
  $'a\nb'
  /dev/null/impossible
)
created_dirs=( ${(0)"$(
  print -rNC1 -- $dirs | ssh user@host '
    perl -MFile::Path=make_path -0le '\''
      @created = make_path(<>, {error => \$err});
      chmod 0555, reverse @created;
      print for @created'\')"}
)

That syntax (contrary to bash's readarray-based one) preserves the exit status of the ssh command, so you could get perl to report errors here, with something like:
#! /bin/zsh -
dirs=(
  'foo/bar baz'
  '../x/y'
  $'a\nb'
  /dev/null/impossible
)
created_dirs=( ${(0)"$(
  print -rNC1 -- $dirs | ssh user@host '
    perl -MFile::Path=make_path -0le '\''
      @created = make_path(<>, {error => \$err});
      for $e (@$err) {
        printf STDERR "making %s: %s\n", %$e;
        $ret = 1;
      }
      for $file (reverse @created) {
        unless (chmod 0555, $file) {
          warn "chmod $file: $!\n";
          $ret = 2;
        }
      }
      print for @created;
      exit $ret;
      '\')"}
)
print "Exit code is $?, $#created_dirs created."
typeset -p created_dirs

Which gives:
making ../x: Permission denied
making ../x/y: No such file or directory
making /dev/null: File exists
making /dev/null/impossible: Not a directory
Exit code is 1, 3 created.
typeset -a created_dirs=( foo 'foo/bar baz' $'a\nb' )

